# How is the measure of an arbitrary set calculated?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I am following Folland's Real Analysis text to learn measure theory and have so far been able to understand how Borel measures are constructed over $\mathbb{R}$ from increasing, right continuous functions. That is, if we have an increasing, right continuous function $F$ then there is a unique Borel measure $\mu_F$ such that
$$\mu_F((a,b]) = F(b)-F(a)$$
for any interval of the form $(a,b]$. This is all good and well, but I am left wondering what happens if we have a more abstract set that is not in a nice "interval" form? How are such sets handled? Do we simply reason them in terms of their interior?

Comment: Are you already familiar with Lebesgue measure? (You certainly don't want to just look at the interior: e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as the union of two sets, each of which has empty interior!)

Comment: @NoahSchweber So far in my studies all I have come across with the Lebesgue measure is that it is the measure where the associated function is $F(x) = x$.

Comment: OK, so taking that as a starting point, we generally define the (outer) Lebesgue measure of an arbitrary set $X$ as the infimum, over all sets $\mathcal{C}$ of intervals covering $X$, of the sum of the lengths of the intervals in $\mathcal{C}$. So for example the outer measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $0$ since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable: fixing $\epsilon>0$, consider putting an open interval of length $\epsilon\cdot 2^{-i}$ around the $i$th rational in your favorite enumeration. On the other hand, you can show via compactness that the outer measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$ *(note that this is nontrivial)*.

Comment: In general, we approach complicated sets by approximating them with collections of simpler ones, then taking infima/suprema as appropriate.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Approximating complicated sets by simpler sets makes sense. I have two questions that follow. First, I imagine constructing this approximation and carrying out the resulting computations can be highly nontrivial, is this often the case? Second (and this might be trivial), I have often seen that $\epsilon \cdot 2^{-i}$ term come up often in measure theory proofs, but have never understood the motivation behind it. Why not simply use an interval of length $\epsilon$?

Comment: Re: your first question, yes, although we often have high-power theorems which can simplify things for us (which themselves are nontrivial). Re: your second question, remember that at the end of the day we're going to add up the lengths of all the intervals involved. If we cover each rational by an interval of length $\epsilon$, this gets "total length" = $\infty$, which is a bit much. Think of $\epsilon$ as our **entire** budget; we don't want to spend it all in one place!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks clears everything up, thank you very much!